# Datepicker required field validation doesn't clear after selecting a date

Tags: html, jquery, validation, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having a problem validating a datepicker text field.

Below is the HTML code for the datepicker textbox:

```
<input type="text" style="width: 150px" id="BirthDate" name="Birthdate" ng-model="Birthdate" required/>
```

and this is the jQuery datepicker function:

```
$("#BirthDate").datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true
});
```

When I select the date from the datepicker, the validation message still shows up.

As soon as I select the date from the datepicker, the 'requires field validation' message should go away.

Could anyone please help me with this?

Comment: Birthday: `<input type="date" name="bday">` 
try this

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<input type="text" style="width: 150px" id="BirthDate" class="required" name="Birthdate"  ng-model="Birthdate" />
```

Answer (score 0):

If you using angular validation then there are you should show validation message with condition where you check property valid and dirty of input. Please checkout this link http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms.

Comment: I'm actually looking for datepicker validation.

Comment: When i select the date from datepicker the dirty property still showing true. When i entet it manually it will turn to false

Comment: You should write custom directive, this may help you http://www.abequar.net/jquery-ui-datepicker-with-angularjs/,  http://cvmlrobotics.blogspot.com/2013/02/angularjs-datepicker-with-jquery.html?m=1